# Отладка сайтов на Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: веб-программирование, windows-phone-8

Каким способом правильнее отлаживать сайты в IE на платформе windows phone 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

Что в Edge, что в Explorer в инструментах разработчика можно выбрать, какое устройство вы хотите эмулировать (Windows Phone 8.0, Windows Phone 8.1), указать разрешение экрана, ориентацию.

Edge:

[image: Эмуляция в Microsoft Edge]
Explorer:

[image: Эмуляция в Internet Explorer]

Comment: Это все отлично, вот только это увы не эмулирует полностью поведение на смартфонах.

Comment: Тогда только на реальном железе.